# Sort / Order Data with two or more filters

Tags: mysql, database, sorting, field, sql-order-by

### how can i sort or order the data below using two fields:

### subject  - year level  - semester

eng1   - 1st year     - 1st semester

eng2   - 1st year     - 2nd semester

eng3   - 2nd year    - 1st semester

eng4   - 2nd year    - 2nd semester

math1  - 1st year    - 1st semester

math2  - 1st year    - 2nd semester

math3  - 2nd year   - 1st semester

math4  - 2nd year   - 2nd semester

in such a way that the data (or subjects) are ordered in the manner below:
1st year 1st semester
1st year 2nd semester
2nd year 1st semester
2nd year 2nd semester

### in short, i'm expecting the output below:

### subject   - year level       - semester

eng1       -  1st year         - 1st semester

math1     -  1st year        - 1st semester

eng2       -  1st year        - 2nd semester

math2     -  1st year        - 2nd semester

eng3      -   2nd year       - 1st semester

math3    -  2nd year        - 1st semester

eng4      -  2nd year        - 2nd semester

math4    -  2nd year       - 2nd semester

Could someone help me with this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `ORDER BY` clause is your friend.

```
SELECT * FROM mytable ORDER BY yearlevel,semester
```

you can also sort ascending or descending:

```
SELECT * FROM mytable ORDER BY yearlevel,semester DESC -- sorts semester descending
```

Answer (score 2):

You can sort multiple field by using order by operator

Example

```
select * from result order by year,sem
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do as following:

```
Select * from your_table_name ORDER BY year_level, semester
```